# (Using Overleaf) transforming operators while transforming lines behave unexpectedly

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, line

I'm going through the official [guide](https://mirror.dogado.de/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) for learning tikz, and I'm currently trying to wrap my head around the transformation operators.

What I learned from the web is that "rotate" rotates around (0,0) unless you use "rotate around", which partly explains the behaviour.

Please take a look at the code below. It draws a grid out of help lines, then draws a line from (0,0) to (0,0.5) and then transforms a following line.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\tikzset{help lines/.style=very thin}
\tikzset{Karl's grid/.style = {help lines,color=#1!50}, Karl's grid/.default = blue}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw[step = 0.5cm, Karl's grid] (-1.4,1.4) grid (1.4,-1.4);
    \draw[thick] (0,0) -- (0,0.5) [xshift = 0cm, xscale = 1.5, rotate = 10] (1,0) -- (1,0.5);
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw[step = 0.5cm, Karl's grid] (-1.4,1.4) grid (1.4,-1.4);
    \draw[thick] (0,0) -- (0,0.5) [xshift = 1cm, xscale = 1.5, rotate = 10] (0,0) -- (0,0.5);
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces the following image:

[image: Compiled image of code above]

As you can see, the transformed line is different in both cases.
The difference is that in the first case, I use *xshift* to shift the line to the right by 1cm, and in the second case I directly increment the x-coordinate by 1.

Now, why does this produce a different output? I assume that shifting takes place at the end, meaning first the x-coordinate is scaled by 1.5, then rotated by 10° and **then** shifted to the right by 1. That's why the first time it ends up at 1 and the second time it ends up at 1.5.

But shouldn't the rotation at least be the same? Why does it sometimes "elevate" the line and sometimes not? It feels like it should always be elevated, to get the 10° angle.

My gut feeling is that shifting somehow moves the point of rotation.

To sum it up: In what order are these operations applied?
Switching *rotate* and *xscale* results in different images, so apparently they are executed when I want them to. :)

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: I edited it to include my whole code, which you could copy and paste. There's nothing to really reduce anymore, that's literally everything.

Comment: Thank you. It's fine now.

Answer (score 1):

> I assume that shifting takes place at the end, meaning first the x-coordinate is scaled by 1.5, then rotated by 10° and then shifted to the right by 1.

No, the transformation are applied when they are called and are valid for the rest of the TeX group (similar on how switches like `\bfseries` or `\itshape` work).

> But shouldn't the rotation at least be the same? Why does it sometimes "elevate" the line and sometimes not? It feels like it should always be elevated, to get the 10° angle.

As you said yourself, the rotation is always around `(0, 0)` but the *current* `(0, 0)`. The origin gets shifted around the same.

> My gut feeling is that shifting somehow moves the point of rotation.

Yup!

---

Let's inspect your **first** drawing:

```
[xshift = 0cm, xscale = 1.5, rotate = 10] (1,0) -- (1,0.5);
```

Every transformation is applied in the order it is called:

- The `xshift = 0cm` obviously doesn't do anything.
- The `xscale` makes it so as if you had written

  ```
  (1.5, 0) -- (1.5, 0.5)
  ```
- And now you rotate that around `(0, 0)` and since all you drawing is above the positive part of the *x* axis it gets “elevated”.

Now the **second**:

```
[xshift = 1cm, xscale = 1.5, rotate = 10] (0,0) -- (0,0.5)
```

Let's go through it again:

- Now, the `xshift = 1cm` does something. It shifts *everything*  including the origin to the right.
- The `xscale` works as before but since you've used only *x* = 0, it doesn't do much in this case. (It **does not** make the shifting be `1.5cm`!)
- Lastly, the rotation. Remember, you rotate around `(0, 0)` (which now sits at the original coordinate `(1cm, 0cm)`) but rotating `(0, 0)` around itself doesn't do much which is why it still sits there.